# How dose the 们 work in sentences

Tags: conjunction

I'm really confused because I was taught that 们 is used as a plural word to do stuff like they and we but the sentence 你们不爱猫 apparently means you do not like cats shouldn't it be they don't like cats?

Answer (score 2):

- 你们 = you (plural)
- 你 = you
- 们 = plural

Perhaps "ya'll" would be another suitable translation.

---

They would be 他们。

他 = Him/Her

Comment: I always interpreted 你们 as "ya'll" in my head even though Duolingo and every other learning source I've tried simply translates it as "you"

Comment: @小奥利奥 Well “ya’ll” is a regional term and “you” can refer to multiple people, so that’s probably why.

Comment: @user3306356 this is not place for your English jargon

Answer (score 1):

你们不爱猫 means you (all) do not like cats/ all of you don't like cats
你不爱猫 means you do not like cats
他们不爱猫 they do not like cats

I guess you are confused because you think "you" must be singular?
"You" can be singular or pural

Comment: yeah thanks I did think you was only singular but after searching it up  I see it can be plural.